# Inline DIV with text goes to bottom of parent

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #dbe2e8;
  padding: 8px;
}

.light-olive {
  background-color: #DFDFD1;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
  /* top: 50px; */
}

.sibling {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #15C26B;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

.child {
  background-color: #ffae0c;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sibling bordered">Sibling</div>
  <div class="sibling bordered"></div>
  <div class="sibling bordered">Sibling</div>
</div>
```

The `div` elements with text in them keep going to the bottom of the parent `div`. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because for inline elements the default [vertical alignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) is baseline. Set it to something like top or middle instead:

```css
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #dbe2e8;
  padding: 8px;
}

.light-olive {
  background-color: #DFDFD1;
}

.relative {
  position: relative;
  /* top: 50px; */
}

.sibling {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #15C26B;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.child {
  background-color: #ffae0c;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="sibling bordered">Sibling</div>
  <div class="sibling bordered"></div>
  <div class="sibling bordered">Sibling</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While I can't fully explain why the `div` elements with text drop to the bottom, I found that you can solve this by adding the property:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to the `.sibling` class.

Answer (score -1):

In order to understand why the divs go below, let's talk about the `display` property you have mentioned for the **sibling**.

```
.sibling {
    display: inline-block;
 }
```

From the name, we can understand that `display:inline-block` declaration shows properties of both `block` and `inline` level elements. In order words its an `inline` element who's width and height can be set or it's a `block` element which doesn't start off from a new line.

In your code, you have mentioned `inline-block` so they don't occupy a single block rather all div's are displayed on the same line somewhat similar to what happens when you apply `float`. Here, the div won't occupy the whole line so when we resize the browser, it tries to fits in all the div's which could be fit into that single line.

Hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: I understand, although this doesn't explain why they're not on the same line vertically. They have the exact same style applied, the only difference is the text in two of the DIVs.

Comment: The text doesn't matter unless you apply a style to that .